# Failed to build gem native extension - error while installing unicorn gem on Ruby 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-14.04, unicorn

I am getting following error while installing `unicorn` on `Ruby 2.2.2`

```
root@magnificent-apps:~# gem install unicorn --no-ri --no-rdoc
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing unicorn:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170116-4446-95pp1l.rb extconf.rb
checking for mmap() in sys/mman.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-atomic_ops-dir
    --without-atomic_ops-dir
    --with-atomic_ops-include
    --without-atomic_ops-include=${atomic_ops-dir}/include
    --with-atomic_ops-lib
    --without-atomic_ops-lib=${atomic_ops-dir}/lib
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:735:in `try_func'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1020:in `block in have_func'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1019:in `have_func'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/raindrops-0.17.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/raindrops-0.17.0/gem_make.out
```

Can anybody suggest how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this from your terminal `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to install all needed dependencies. It did trick for me.